# Expected number of bags to get one ball of each color

Tags: probability, expected-value, coupon-collector

There are bags with n balls, and each ball can have any of the n different colors with equal probability. A bag can contain each color multiple times. What is the expected number of bags until we get at least one ball of each color?

The closest problem I could find is the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem), but in that problem you buy the boxes one by one, whereas in this problem you can only select a multiple of n balls.

What I got so far is the expected number if we are only interested in getting one specific color $i$, which would then have a geometric distribution with $p=1-(\dfrac{n-1}{n})^n$, since getting color $i$ in a bag would be the complement of getting n balls with a color other than $i$, but I feel like this not the right direction.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  A natural starting point might be to work this out for small $n$.  Also note that Linearity of Expectation is your friend here.  I should also note that your title question and the question in the body are not the same.

Comment: Similar thinking to coupon collector gets you there.  What is the chance the first ball is a new color?  The second?  The third?

Comment: How many bags are there?  You seem to have left this out.  Or are you perhaps asking for the expected number of bags *until* getting a bag with a ball of each color?  Note, since there are $n$ colors and $n$ balls, the statement "*at least one ball of each color*" is the same as "*exactly one ball of each color*"

Comment: I just edited the question, sorry if it was not clear. It is just a variation of the coupon collector's where you draw n coupons instead of just 1 at each step.

Comment: This is a special case of the question I closed this as a duplicate of, with the number $b$ of coupons per batch equal to the number $n$ of coupons. I use the occasion to make everyone who's reading this aware of the [list of generalizations of common questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29382), where I collected many of the variations of the coupon collector's problem that keep getting asked on the site.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**

OP has modified the question after the answer was posted so that now it is a well known coupon collector problem with multiple coupons in each packet. The answer below addresses what I understood to be the original query

---

It is always good to change abstract problems so that they come within the milieu of familiar types.

So consider, as a parallel for one bag, that a normal die is thrown $6$ times, what is the probability that you get each number exactly once ?

You will immediately say, $Pr = \Large\frac{6!}{6^6}$, won't you ?

So for $n$ colors, for any particular bag, $Pr = \Large\frac{n!}{n^n}$

and applying linearity of expectation, we just multiply the above expression by $b$, the number of bags.

Comment: @lulu: I went by the sentence *"What is the expected number of bags that will contain at least one ball of each color?"*

Comment: I just edited the question but @lulu is correct that it is just a variation of the coupon collector's problem.

Comment: @MustafaEnesBatur: I have added a note.